# Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001 Error: Connecting to Metro bundler failed

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, bundler, metro-bundler

Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Error: Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
at _waitForRunningAsync (C:\xdl@59.0.27\src\start\startLegacyReactNativeServerAsync.ts:342:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at startReactNativeServerAsync (C:\xdl@59.0.27\src\start\startLegacyReactNativeServerAsync.ts:285:3)
at startAsync (C:\xdl@59.0.27\src\start\startAsync.ts:61:5)

I had developed an app using React-Native for frontend and react and MongoDB for the backend.when i try to run the front-end app, i recieve the following error. i have tried removing .expo directory, reinstalling expo, but still not working. someone help!!

Answer (score 1):

Am not saying that this best solution but from packager-info.json

```
    {
  "devToolsPort": 19002,
  **"expoServerPort": 19000,
  "packagerPort": 19001,
  "packagerPid": 2588,**
  "expoServerNgrokUrl": null,
  "packagerNgrokUrl": null,
  "ngrokPid": null,
  "webpackServerPort": null
}
```

I replaced it with this

```
    {
  "devToolsPort": 19002,
  "expoServerPort": null,
  "packagerPort": null,
  "packagerPid": null,
  "expoServerNgrokUrl": null,
  "packagerNgrokUrl": null,
  "ngrokPid": null,
  "webpackServerPort": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your metro bundler is probably not running. You need to start it with `expo start`. Usually this is the start also to afterwards start the frontend. Be careful not to stop it in your terminal afterwards. The terminal needs to stay open and running when you are running the app.
And make sure your device is connected with the same network as your system is.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Windows 11 WMIC is an optional feature and without it Expo uses 127.0.0.1 for LAN.  I opened up a [bug report for it](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/24759) but installing WMIC should fix your issue.